# Iphone app is not responsive for some time after phonecall made from app (with webview) finishes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, nsnotifications

I make call from my app with this code (i use webview because after the call finishes, i dont want to show dialer app ):

```
UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:callWebview];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tel];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];
```

I detect end of call with subscribing to notification:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ctCallStateDidChange1:) name:@"CTCallStateDidChange" object:nil];

   - (void)ctCallStateDidChange1:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
     NSString *call = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"callState"];
     if ([call isEqualToString:CTCallStateDisconnected])
    { 
       NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Obvestilo" message:@"Some text?"
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles: @"No", nil];
            [alert show];
        }       
    }       
}
```

I need to show alertview after the call finishes and control is returend to my app, but sometimes it takes some time when the end of call is detected with notification and my app stays nonresponsive during this period.

Do you have any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detection of end of call with notifications is correct. What i had to do is to add this line after the call was finished (so the command executed on main thread):

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                [self showAlert];
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please expline more your what you need exactly !!!!! after reading you code, i concluded that you want save a event handler that you notify if state of call !! No ?

First You need to save event Handler in you Apps before you make you call like that ok : 

1. `CTCallCenter *callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall* call)
{
if (call.callState == CTCallStateDisconnected)`enter code here`
{
NSLog(@"Call has been disconnected");
// you can do any things here, your treatment
}
else if (call.callState == CTCallStateConnected)
{
NSLog(@"Call has just been connected");
// you can do any things here, your treatment
}
else if(call.callState == CTCallStateIncoming)
{
NSLog(@"Call is incoming");
// you can do any things here, your treatment
}
else
{http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9911993/edit
NSLog(@"None of the conditions");
// you can do any things here, your treatment
}
}; 
`
2. you need indicated to the system that you want let you apps alive in background and make call by the code : 
`UIApplication *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    {
        DLog(@"supporte Multitasking");
    }else
    {
        return;
    }`

    `backgroundTask = [appDelegate beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // DLog(@"beginTask");

    }];`

    `NSString *tel = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingFormat:@"12345"];
    [appDelegate openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tel]];`


3. For returne in you application registry event UILocalNotification and implement this method in you delegate
` #pragma mark local notification
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
`
i hope that help you
```

Comment: i need to show alertview after a call finishes and ios returns from dialer app to my app.

Comment: First Look at : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603

Comment: Yes, i am using core telephony to detect end of call.